# What is this yellow-pink flower?

Tags: botany, species-identification, flowers

Found in **[Pennsylvania, Philadelphia County](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphia_County,_Pennsylvania)**

This is intentionally planted, not sure if it is indigenous to this region. Thank you for your expertise!

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It resembles ***[Lantana Camara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lantana_camara)***, from the family of **[Verbenaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbenaceae)** that is native to American tropics according to Wikipedia.

They come in variety of different colors, and the one you have photographed is the **[Pink Caprice](http://www.finegardening.com/pink-caprice-lantana-lantana-camara-pink-caprice)**.

[image: Pink Caprice]

**Image Source:** **[Cindy Dyer's Blog](https://cindydyer.wordpress.com/tag/lantana-pink-caprice/)**

Comment: Glad I could help :)